# Bash: Local variable are removed after global variable are set

Tags: bash, terminal

### Background

I am a Window user trying to switch to linux as my daily driver so I am currently on Arch Linux using KDE.  I am relatively new to this.

I am trying to learn some bash scripting and following a tutorial on this.  It has me write the following commands in my shell.  FYI, this is all done in the terminal and not in a script.

### Problem

```
set MY_VAR=42
set | grep MY_VAR
```

The output comes out as expected

```
_=MY_VAR=42
```

However, when I write:

```
export MY_GLOBAL_VAR="fun with vars"
set | grep 'MY_*'
```

I am expecting the following output

```
MY_GLOBAL_VAR='fun with vars'
_=MY_VAR=42
```

But what I get is:

```
MY_GLOBAL_VAR='fun with vars'
_='MY_GLOBAL_VAR=fun with vars'
```

### What I have tried

I try to get output MY_VAR using and echo but get nothing.  I tried doing a grep for only MY_VAR like the first step but I get nothing.

If I reverse the order of declaring the variables, it works.  So if I declare the global first then the local, the `set | grep 'MY_*` gives me the expected output.

I have been searching the internet for hours and have not found explanation for this behavior.  I have tried in two different terminals "Konsole" and "Alacritty".

It is acting as if the global variable is completely remove the local one that I set earlier.

I have tried using completely different variable names and the same thing happened

```
set TESTING=42
export MY_GLOBAL_VAR="fun with vars"
set | grep "TESTING"
echo $TESTING
```

Both return nothing.

I haven't switched to zsh or any other shell yet as I am wanting to start with bash before moving on to something else.

Comment: `set` doesn't set a variable at all in POSIX-family shells like bash. That's not its purpose.

Comment: Just `TESTING=42` sets the variable `TESTING`. Do not put `set` first.

Comment: The variable `$_` contains the last argument of the last command you typed. That's why you see `_=MY_VAR=42` in the first output. Why would you expect to see it again later?

Comment: (and btw, all-caps names are used for variables that reflect or modify behavior of the shell and other built-in utilities; you should use names with at least one lowercase character for variables you define yourself; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable, so the same naming conventions apply to both categories; thus, it's better to name your variable `testing` or `my_global_var`, not `TESTING` or `MY_GLOBAL_VAR`).

Comment: See the bash man-page, section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_, for the proper (and somewhat obscure) use of the command `set`.